# Matlab fit function method

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, data-fitting

My apologies if this is not a suitable question for stackoverflow.

Fitting a curve to my data with

```
f = fit(x,up,'exp2', 'Exclude', [0])
```

It works fine, but how does the fit function calculate the fit? Is it linear regression?

It is not in the documentation

https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html

Comment: What is the option `'exp2'`? It is not a documented method (i.e. `poly1 / poly11 / poly2 / linearinterp / cubicinterp / smoothingspline / lowess`)... And what are you trying to do with the `'Exclude'` option here? Doesn't seem to match the `[0]` parameter (which it should).

Comment: The doc is [here](https://mathworks.com/help/curvefit/list-of-library-models-for-curve-and-surface-fitting.html)

Comment: It's a 2 term exponential - this is the output it gives me:  <br/>

`f = 

     General model Exp2:
     f(x) = a*exp(b*x) + c*exp(d*x)
     Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       a =      0.5486  (0.4603, 0.6368)
       b =    -0.02263  (-0.02841, -0.01684)
       c =      0.6042  (0.5842, 0.6243)
       d =  -0.0006956  (-0.0007257, -0.0006656)`

Comment: And for exclude I'm ignoring the zeros in the data.